# What happens when Raid 10 Arrays are full?

Tags: raid, storage, raid10

I've been researching recommended raid types for Database storage, VMs, as well as other server related uses, and the common answer I see is Raid 10, for performance and protection.

It is my understanding that a Raid 10 array can't be expanded when storage runs out.

So the question is, what happens? Do people just add more drives and create a second raid 10 array? Or do they create a second, larger Raid 10 array, transfer data from the old on to it, and then remove the original array?

Comment: `It is my understanding that a Raid 10 array can't be expanded when storage runs out.` - Where did you read that? This is completely dependent upon the RAID controller. I've added HDD's to our Dell PowerVault MD3620F RAID 10 array many times.

Comment: Well I'm looking specifically at the Dell VRTX and it says in the documentation that Raid 10 can't be expanded.

Comment: OK, that's a specific piece of hardware that doesn't support expansion. That doesn't mean that that's applicable to every piece of hardware. If you need the ability to add drives to an existing RAID 10 array then you'll need to find hardware that supports it. As for your actual question, if a specific piece of hardware doesn't support expansion then one solution would be to back up the data, replace the existing drives with larger drives, create a new RAID 10 array, and restore the data.

Comment: So waht? Most OS these days can split a volume over multiple discs. Use that to split it over multiple RAID 10 volumes. Done.

Comment: I thought as much. Most pieces of hardware I have seen so far doesn't support it, so it's interesting to hear that it is possible. I was also looking at the Dell SN series of SANs, which also can't do it I don't think.